# Which OO Framework provides the smoothest transition from the C WinAPI: VCL, MFC, or qt?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I am interested in the pros and cons of these three frameworks, for someone who is used to the WinAPI/C environment. The code to be turned OO is not very complex: about 3000 lines of code, mostly controls. I would like to make the program OO, to make it maintainable by others down the road. At the moment it is a big ball of C mud, and I want to recode it in C++ OO.

Which of those frameworks should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Visual Component Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library) (VCL) is a library that was developed by Borland for their products (Delphi, and C++ Builder).
- [Microsoft Foundation Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) (MFC) is library developed by Microsoft, and essentially is a C++ wrapper around the C WinAPI. It is not included with Visual C++ 2005/2008/2010 Express, though.
- As the Wikipedia article for MFC says, [Windows Template Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library) (WTL) is a C++ template library that is lightweight alternative for MFC. There is no official documentation, although it is being build [here](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/wtldoc.htm). (See [this page](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/all_wtl.htm) for examples, controls, and utilities.) WTL doesn't have integration with IDEs, and it is not officially supported by the [Product Support Services](http://support.microsoft.com).
- [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29) is a cross-platform C++ framework which is available in three licenses (GNU LGPL 2.1 with Qt special exception, GNU GPL 3.0, Commercial Developer License). Being cross-platform, the framework is not a wrapper around the C WinAPI library. It has also bindings for different programming languages.
  The API style used from Qt is the native one, in the latest versions; previously, it was emulating the native GUI (except where Qt is the native GUI, such as in KDE).
  There isn't a simple, complete example, which is not too long, and too basic to make you understand the differences between Qt, and C WinAPI, but you can find some examples [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/all-examples.html). I will say there are specific concepts that are used through all the framework, such as the concept of signal (in short, the event raised from a widget), and slot (in short, the method called when the event is raised), which allows you to change what shown from a widget basing on the value of other widgets.

  ```
  connect(xSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), glWidget, SLOT(setXRotation(int)));
  connect(glWidget, SIGNAL(xRotationChanged(int)), xSlider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
  connect(ySlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), glWidget, SLOT(setYRotation(int)));
  connect(glWidget, SIGNAL(yRotationChanged(int)), ySlider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
  connect(zSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), glWidget, SLOT(setZRotation(int)));
  connect(glWidget, SIGNAL(zRotationChanged(int)), zSlider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
  ```

  If you are looking for a library that allows you to build cross-platform applications, or in different programming languages, this is what I would choose. Keep in consideration the license under which you get Qt, thought.

If you want to create a C++ application running only on Windows, I would choose WTL too. Respect some years ago, it is easier to use it now, although there is not a support for IDEs, which means (for example) there isn't a wizard to create an instance of a UI class, or to create a sub-class of a GUI class.

Answer (score 0):

MFC and WTL both are closest to WinAPI, because is just a OOP wrappers on WinAPI. This is a most short way to convert C code to C++. QT is more robust and modern, but you must make complete redesign your project. I suggest to use WTL.